# app crashing after trying to send a message to a auto respond chat

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, messaging

my app is crashing when i'm trying to send a message in my " Contact Us " activity.
I'm new to programming, so i'm trying to rely on tuts at the moment.
Here are my codes:

**Logcat error**

```
    I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@14d37fce time:3633891094
I/System.out: normalized = hi
I/System.out: No match.
I/System.out: writeCertainIFCaegories learnf.aiml size= 0
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.lrtapp.ardentmap, PID: 20001
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.lrtapp.ardentmap.Adapter.ChatMessageAdapter.getView(ChatMessageAdapter.java:61)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1344)
                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1663)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2098)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20001 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

**Contact class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.lrtapp.ardentmap.Adapter.ChatMessageAdapter;
import com.lrtapp.ardentmap.Model.ChatMessage;

import org.alicebot.ab.AIMLProcessor;
import org.alicebot.ab.Bot;
import org.alicebot.ab.Chat;
import org.alicebot.ab.MagicStrings;
import org.alicebot.ab.PCAIMLProcessorExtension;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Contact extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    FloatingActionButton btnSend;
    EditText edtTextMsg;
    ImageView imageView;

    private Bot bot;
    public static Chat chat;
    private ChatMessageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        edtTextMsg = findViewById(R.id.user_message);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(this, new ArrayList<ChatMessage>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String message = edtTextMsg.getText().toString();

                String response = chat.multisentenceRespond(edtTextMsg.getText().toString());

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
                    Toast.makeText(Contact.this, "Enter a query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                sendMessage(message);
                botsReply(response);

                //clear editText
                edtTextMsg.setText("");
                listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount() -1 );

            }
        });

        boolean available = isSDCartAvailable();

        AssetManager assets = getResources().getAssets();
        File fileName = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "TBC/bots/TBC");

        boolean makeFile = fileName.mkdirs();

        if (fileName.exists()){
            //read the line
            try {
                for(String dir : assets.list("TBC")){
                    File subDir = new File(fileName.getPath() + "/" + dir);
                    boolean subDir_Check = subDir.mkdirs();

                    for(String file : assets.list("TBC" + dir)){
                        File newFile = new File(fileName.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);

                        if(newFile.exists()){
                            continue;
                        }

                        InputStream in;
                        OutputStream out;
                        in = assets.open("TBC/" + dir + "/" + file);
                        out = new FileOutputStream(fileName.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);

                        //copy files from assets  to the mobile's sd card or any secondary storage

                        copyFile(in, out);
                        in.close();
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //get the working directory
        MagicStrings.root_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TBC";
        AIMLProcessor.extension = new PCAIMLProcessorExtension();

        bot = new Bot("TBC", MagicStrings.root_path, "chat");
        chat = new Chat(bot);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isSDCartAvailable() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)? true : false;
    }

    private void botsReply(String response) {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(false, false, response);
        adapter.add(chatMessage);
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(false, true, message);
        adapter.add(chatMessage);
    }
}
```

**Contact xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Contact">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnSend"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">

    </ListView>

 <EditText
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnSend"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:id="@+id/user_message"
     android:hint="Enter your message"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSend"
        android:src="@drawable/bot" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**gradle build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'chat-message-view'

    publishedGroupId = 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview'
    libraryName = 'chat-message-view'
    artifact = 'chat-message-view'

    libraryDescription = 'Android library to create chat message view easily'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.7'

    developerId = 'himanshu-soni'
    developerName = 'Himanshu Soni'
    developerEmail = 'himanshusoni.me@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.cpiz:BubbleView:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.Google:gson:1.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    //implementation 'com.cpiz.bubbleview:bubbleview:{X.Y.Z}'
    //Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/Ab.jar')
    //implementation 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.7'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**permissions used in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

Thanks in advance to the people that will respond. Any answer will be very appreciated. I'm sorry if the codes are messy.

Comment: The stacktrace says `@drawable/bot` isn't a Drawable, color or path. Show the contents of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error log: the problem is the drawable for the `ImageView`.  
Make sure it exists in `drawable` folder.  
Maybe you stored it in a subfolder like `drawable-v21` so it can't be found.

Comment: @Zeke because it is there in your resources but at runtime depending on the android version of the emulator /device, AS will search for the drawable in the folder matching this version.

Comment: so, I should make a xml file in the drawable folder that contains the bot icon and call it?

Comment: @Zeke if you already have this drawable in another folder, just right click/copy from its folder and right click/paste in the main drawable folder.

Comment: Hi, it solved the problem, but now im facing another problem. I just edited my question. But thanks!

Comment: @Zeke the error is about a null TextView in ChatMessageAdapter class

Comment: Thanks! will just post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `@drawable/bot` in your **ImageView** cannot be found. Try replacing it. Make sure the the drawable filename does not use dashes

- `file-name.xml` - bad
- `file_name.xml` - good

Comment: but why does it show a picture when i place that drawable bot?